Can i use Firebase Analytics within my own SDK/library?
I only want to capture logs from the screens within the SDK. Is it possible?
The library does not have an app module.
I added the Firebase Analytics dependencies to the library. I also added the google-services.json file to the library.
Error in logcat;
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.sdk. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

No, it's not possible.  Analytics collects data for an application, not a library distributed for multiple applications.
